# Blazor call a method on Property Value Change

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

i am looking for a way to call a method when value of a property is change (**Not By USER**)

e.g i have this property

`[Parameter]public int SelectedPatientId { get; set; }`

and when ever its value changes i want to call this method

```
public async void valuechanged()
{
... do something here
}
```

so far i tried this and it's not working

`<input type="hidden" value="@SelectedPatientId" @onchange="valuechanged"/>`

`<input type="hidden" @bind="@SelectedPatientId" @bind:event="valuechanged"/>`

Comment: You can call `valuechanged` in the setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call on the setter :

```cs
int _selectedPatientId;
[Parameter]public int SelectedPatientId 
{ 
    get => _selectedPatientId;
    set
    {
        _selectedPatientId = value;
        valuechanged();
    }
}
```

> An asnc method should not return void but Task or ValueTask

```cs
public async Task valuechanged()
{
... do something here
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's what i'm looking for

Comment: I'm looking into doing the exact same thing, but this isn't a good solution. Exceptions will be discarded, and what if you need the return value of the async function?

Comment: I'm noting that in the PropertyChanged callback sample, MS is doing a "call-and-forget" on an async method in a property setter: `set => PropertyChanged.InvokeAsync(value);`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1